# Welcome message, wrong link

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-users, global-inbox, private-messaging

When joining first message in inbox was:

> [image: [I] welcome 1 min ago Welcome to Stack Overflow! Take the 2-minute site tour to earn your first badge.]

This message links to:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current
```

Assume it should be:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/tour
```

or similar.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com

Comment: ...AGAIN? Cache is a pain in da ___. Ugh.

Comment: Uhh, how does this have anything to do with caching?

Comment: Localization, it's always localization

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We had an A/B testing malfunction here.

A while ago (October!), we were testing alternate links and text for the welcome message, and ended up settling on the text you see.

The other text was removed, but the links were not (the text and link live in different locations in code - yay localization!). When the test was stopped, the result was the text you see, but the *other* link.

I have fixed this and this is in the next build (rev 2015.1.12.2164, meta rev 2015.1.12.2934).